# R: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1) for vegdist

Tags: r

I am trying to make a dissimilarity matrix by using the following code:

```
BC26bBrayCurtisMatrix<-vegdist(BC2_6b_OTU, method="bray", binary=FALSE, diag=FALSE, upper=FALSE,na.rm = FALSE)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in vegdist(BC2_6b_OTU, method = "bray", binary = FALSE, diag = FALSE, NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

I have tried:

```
is.na(BC2_6b_OTU)
```

The output returns all FALSE except for 2 columns at the end of the table. These are actually blank on my BC2_6b_OTU.csv file but say 'TRUE' after this is.na output.  Could this be the problem? If so, how do I delete this row?

[image: Photo of R output for is.na]

Any other suggestions? I am new to R and I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove certain columns, you can do

```
x <- x[, c(ncol(x), ncol(x)-1)]
```

or

```
x <- x[ , !sapply(x, FUN = function(n) any(is.na(n))))
```

My guess would be that this .csv was created in a spreadsheet program? If so, consider removing "empty" columns at the end of the dataset and work on a clean set.

Here's a demonstration that NAs can cause your problem.

```
library(vegan)

data(varespec)
vare.dist <- vegdist(varespec)

varespec$sneakycol1 <- NA
varespec$sneakycol2 <- NA

sneaky.dist <- vegdist(varespec, method = "bray")
```

Comment: Actually, this removed everything EXCEPT the last column. I used the code: 
 BC2_6b_OTU_NA <- BC2_6b_OTU[, c(ncol(BC2_6b_OTU), ncol(BC2_6b_OTU)-1)]

Comment: @LizKimbrough just add minus in front of col numbers and it will exclude them.